# XMLHttpRequest response returning "Null", Even Though the Response Body is Present

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I'm a fairly novice programmer currently working on a chrome extension intended to automatically restore the response folders of google forms. The extension mainly operates by intercepting HttpRequests made by the form upon launch, one of these requests is crucial to the operation of the extension. A "checkfolders" POST request is made by the form, and, if intercepted, copied, and than sent from the extension, the full response body is returned. It's relatively small containing a true or false variable:

```
{"fileuploadfolderswritable":true,"status":0}
```

This variable indicates whether or not the form needs restoration. Looking at the network requests made from my Chrome Extension, the request works perfectly fine, and the full response body is returned with no errors. However, req.response as shown below, comes up as null.

```
function Get_Folder_Status(url){  //var url = Intercepted Http Response
  const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  
  req.open("POST", url.href, true);  //url.href = Request Url
  req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  //Send Request to Check Folder Status of Form
  req.responseType = "json";
  req.onload = Check_Folder(req.response)
  req.send()
}
```

There is most likely some small detail that I'm missing, I've already spent quite a while fiddling with variables like the responseType and headers with no success. I've viewed other threads about a "null" response with no direct answer to my specific problem, so I hope I was descriptive enough to give some insight to what the issue may be. The sending of the request has no errors whatsoever, so it must be how I'm handling the response.

Comment: onload should be a function, not a call, e.g. `req.onload = () => Check_Folder(req.response)`

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you! That seemed to make it work :D